# How can I build a hierarchical JAR file for a library with SBT?

Tags: sbt

I am working at a library needing some dependencies.
For ease of deployment, I want to create a JAR file containing everything, including the dependencies.

I have tried sbt-assembly - this works, but it may be inadvisable due to legal reasons, so I'm looking for a solution where the resulting JAR file has the original JAR files inside, and where the classpath entry in MANIFEST.MF is set up such that client classes may just add this "nested JAR file" into their classpaths.

Is something like this even possible? sbt-one-jar nearly does, what I want, but only for executables - my product will result in a library, so this is not a perfect fit.

As I've used SBT so far, an SBT plugin would be easiest to use, as it is rather too much work to convert everyting to maven or gradle or ... now.

Comment: What is the legal argument? Technically there is really no difference whether you have jars inside a jar or the .class files. After all a jar is just a virtual file system.

Comment: The license for this library says we are not allowed to modify it. It is not clear if re-packaging counts as "modification" - we just want to keep it watertight.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking a bit more about how class lookup works, we dediced to abandon this experiment.
Basically classes are loaded by ClassLoader instances, and the standard class loaders for applications use a fixed strategy of how to find classes in JAR files or directories.
It seems that to allow a library to be located in a hierarchical JAR file, we must also provide the **user** of this library (i.e. the library client) with a special classloader so that our client may load all needed classes from the hierarchical JAR.

This is too much work to be worth it - the whole idea of a hierarchical JAR was enteratained only to simplify deployment, and having to juggle own classloaders would nullify this simplification.

In short - possible, but probably not worth the effort.